# What is the best way to change a large number of data properties in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

Here is my data

```
data() {
        return {
            monday_start: '',
            monday_end: '',
            tuesday_start: '',
            tuesday_end: '',
            wednesday_start: '',
            wednesday_end: '',
            thursday_start: '',
            thursday_end: '',
            friday_start: '',
            friday_end: '',
            saturday_start: '',
            saturday_end: '',
            sunday_start: '',
            sunday_end: '',
            notifmsg: '',
        };
    },
```

I have a calendar system where you can set the start and end of a day like so:

```
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Monday</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <base-time-picker
                                                    :input-data.sync="monday_start"
                                                    field="monday_start"
                                                    label="Monday - Start Time"
                                                    :long-time="true"
                                                    class="mb-3"
                                                />
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <base-time-picker
                                                    :input-data.sync="monday_end"
                                                    field="monday_end"
                                                    label="Monday - End Time"
                                                    :long-time="true"
                                                    class="mb-3"
                                                />
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <v-icon
                                                    class="ml-2"
                                                    @click="copy(monday_start,monday_end)"
                                                >
                                                    mdi-compare
                                                </v-icon>
                                                <v-icon
                                                    class="ml-2"
                                                    @click="reset('monday')"
                                                >
                                                    mdi-delete
                                                </v-icon>
                                            </td>
                                       </tr>
```

I have created a function called copy so you can copy the day across all other days( so you don't have to individually set each day)

```
copy(start,end){
        this.monday_start = start;
        this.tuesday_start = start;
        this.wednesday_start = start;
        this.thursday_start = start;
        this.friday_start = start;
        this.saturday_start = start;
        this.sunday_start = start;
        this.monday_end = end;
        this.tuesday_end = end;
        this.wednesday_end = end;
        this.thursday_end = end;
        this.friday_end = end;
        this.saturday_end = end;
        this.sunday_end = end;
    },
```

Obviously, this isn't clean and wanted to know the best way of changing all of this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your stated environment, assuming no other variables have the specified keywords:

You could utilise `Object.keys()` on your VueJS instance and check for `_start` `_end` keywords. After building an array, just assign them your new values.

```
copy(copyDateStart, copyDateEnd) {
    Object.keys(this).filter(key => key.includes('_start')).forEach(key => this[key] = copyDateStart);
    Object.keys(this).filter(key => key.includes('_end')).forEach(key => this[key] = copyDateEnd);
}
```

Here is a [working example over on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L9xsctro/1/) (Vanilla JS to demonstrate).

---

References:

- [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/object/keys)
- [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/array/includes)
- [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/array/filter)